# How to redirect part of a URL using regex?

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, redirect

So I am having a bit of trouble.

I have many products with the same part o URL that I recently changed:

```
https://www.website.com/shop/category-sample/product1/
https://www.website.com/shop/category-sample/product2/
https://www.website.com/shop/category-sample/product3/
https://www.website.com/shop/category-sample/product4/
```

I need the "category-sample" to be "category"

So the new URLS would look like this:

```
https://www.website.com/shop/category/product1/
```

And etc.

Thank you!

Comment: What webserver? Do you have mod_rewrite?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. I am on managed hosting for wordpress via Kinsta, so it's serving on Nginx. 

I do have Yoast installed, however Im not sure how to set that up using their Regex redirect.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you are using the typical apache http server with loaded rewriting module this should do what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?shop/category-sample/(.*)$ /shop/category/$1 [R=301,QSA,END]
```

In case "category" actually is a dynamic value, not a fixed literal this variant should do what you ask for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?shop/(.+)-sample/(.*)$ /shop/$1/$2 [R=301,QSA,END]
```

That rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration of in a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" style file) if you have to use those.

If you receive an "internal server error" using those rules (http status 500) then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. Have a try using the `L` flag instead of the newer `END` flag then. You will find a corresponding hint in your http servers error log file in that case.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).